# How to Mock file and File content with NUit

Tags: c#, nunit

Hello I have the following scenario:

Configuration files are stored in a specific folder (and sub folders), the structure looks something like below, with `.conf` files containing XML and `.conf.json` contains JSON

```
- Config
|- main_config.json
|- in/
   |- mod1.conf
   |- mod2.conf.json
   |- mod3.conf
   |- ...
|- out/ 
   |- mod1.conf.json
   |- mod2.conf
   |- ...
```

In my project I have a class that encapsulates the existence of these files, such that it is not exposed in the rest of the software.
I do not parse a reader or writer of any form (dependency injection, etc) to this class it is all handled internally.
In the encapsulation I read the models contained in the configuration files and then validate them using FluentValidation.

Now my issue is I want to test this flow in a unit test, but I cannot find a way to mock the file system, so how to do this?
Let me expand a little bit, if I did parse the reader and writer using dependency injection, this is easy. But that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: If the encapsulating class handles the writing and writing of the files internally without requesting its dependencies (reader and writer) via DI, writing an unit test will be impossible.
A unit test is based on the fact that to test this particular _unit_, all other parts can be mocked away.
So either abstract the filesystem (e. g. `IFileSystem`) or write an integration test.

Comment: Yeah I suspect I needed an integration test.

Comment: I'll convert it to an answer - then you can decide whether you wanna close the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the encapsulating class handles the writing and writing of the files internally without requesting its dependencies (reader and writer) via DI, writing a unit test will be impossible.
A unit test is based on the fact that to test this particular *unit*, all other parts can be mocked away.

So either abstract the filesystem (e. g. `IFileSystem`) or write an integration test.